# How to name a row in a Matlab dataset without causing indexing error?

Tags: matlab, dataset, rows

I'm new to using Matlab and am trying to name rows in my data set. However, I keep getting an error that says: "Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds (must
not exceed 1)" for any row except the first row (titled year). Curiously, it works for the first row ("year") so I do not know what's going on.

```
rgdp = importdata('GDP.csv')
year = rgdp.data(1,:);
gdp = rgdp.data(2,:);
%c = rgdp.data(3,:);
%i = rgdp.data(8,:);
%g = rgdp.data(23,:);
%e = rgdp.data(17,:);
%m = rgdp.data(20,:);
```

Index in position 1 exceeds array bounds (must
not exceed 1).

Error in Question_4 (line 4)
gdp = rgdp.data(2,:);

Comment: The index in position number one, i.e., then `2`, is out of array bounds. This is because the array bounds is 1, and it must not exceed that. What of that do you not understand, so we can help you?

Comment: I'm trying to name the row as "gdp". I saw that you can name columns using, for example, rgdp.data(:,2); and that you usually name rows using (2,:) format, but that is not working here.

Comment: Because that variable only has 1 row, there are not 2 rows. That is what the error is saying

Comment: Viewing the arrays in the workspace window may help to give a visual. Variable `rgdp.data` created from the imported `.csv` file seems to only have a single row. This causes `rgdp.data(2,:)` to throw an error since there is no second row that can be indexed.